# Authorizing a user's action in a one page javascript application

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, authorization, singlepage

We have a CakePHP application that uses ACL and Roles to handle user authorization. Right now the entire admin panel is built using ExtJS3, so they're all single page views. Anytime a view is loaded we use ACL to see if the user is authorized to access that part of the application.

We're looking to move our app to Rails and use ExtJS4 with the new MVC/Single page structure. We're curious how we would go about authorizing users actions? Right now they're very granular. A user's authorization can be locked down by actions, so they might be able to access index, and read or index, read, update, but not destroy etc.

If the page just loads once, and ExtJS takes care of loading all of the subviews of the app what's the best way to authorize a user by role?

Any ideas?

**Edit** I forgot to add that we need the ability to add/remove roles or abilities from the admin area. Something like cancan would be great, but I haven't seen a way to make it dynamic to where a user can add/edit abilities.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good library for me so far is [cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan).  It has the ability to be fairly granular and customizable from what I've seen, yet centralized in defining abilities for example.  Hope this helps! EDIT: It's available in ruby gems as well-- `gem install cancan` should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks, but I forgot one important aspect in my original post. See the edited post above. Sorry man. Great answer though!

Comment: I should mention that the same author has several other ruby gems that look promising for what you want.  One in particular that I've not used yet but will probably try at some point, given its being an extension of cancan is cantango, which can be found [here](http://rubygems.org/gems/cantango) and [here(github)](https://github.com/kristianmandrup/cantango).  It is designed, for instance, to do exactly what you want and allow roles to be administered via a web interface, for example.  Hope this helps you with that last requirement :)